# What resource qualifiers should I set for screen density/size like Motorola TC55

Tags: android, android-resources, screen-size, motorola-droid

I have to set specific "values" and "layout" folders that work only for devices with the same screen specs of the [Motorola TC55](https://www.zebra.com/gb/en/products/mobile-computers/handheld/tc55/tc55-spec-sheet.html).

What qualifier should I write?

Here are the screen of the Motorola TC55 display info:

[image: Display info page 1]

**UPDATE:** following [this site](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2784/best-way-to-support-540x960-and-480x800-both-hdpi) I have done the following formula: 480 / (240 / 160) = **320**

so I have tried the folders: **values-sw320dp** and **values-w320dp**.

They work correctely with the Motorola TC55, but the problem is that it also affects the Samsung Note 3 device.

The formula for the Note 3 is: 1080 / (480 / 160) = **360**

So why it also affects device with different Density-independent pixel ?

Comment: by `same`, you mean `exact same`? what have you tried?

Comment: *Resource qualifiers* does not quite sound right. Are you asking for AVD settings? (I think you are, but I want to make sure you are not talking about something else).

Comment: Do you have the device you could use this to determine: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sturnus.screeninfo

Comment: I mean exact the same screen size. I have updated the questio with the info taken from the app that ligi adviced me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done a quick test regarding the layout, starting from the information available in [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts).

In my case I've worked with a TC55 (320x533 dp) and a TC70 (360x640 dp).

I got to use a specific different layout in the two devices using the folder specifier:

```
layout-sw320dp
layout-sw360dp
```

The first one for the TC55 and the second one used by the TC70.

Comment: Perfect answer, with link and description. Thumbs up for you PFM